EKS a service with external ip endpoints is not forwarding requests properly
I have a set of IPs outside of the k8s cluster which i want to loadbalance natively. The way to do that is using a clusterIP service without a selector and defining a endpoint resource with the ips i want to forward. When I do that, the service discovers the ips, but does not forward requests to them.
I dont have any network policies and this is on AWS EKS. I already turned off source/dest flag
